# Decoding a nullable heterogeneous dictionary

Tags: swift, codable

I need to decode a dictionary of the form `[(Heterogeneous object): CGFloat]?`. I've got working extensions on the `KeyedDecodingContainer` that allow me to decode lists of and single heterogeneous objects however I'm struggling to convert these to work with a dictionary. Here is the working method for a optional array:

```
func decodeArrayIfPresent<T : Decodable, U : ClassFamily>(family: U.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> [T]? {
    do {
        var container = try self.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key)
        var list = [T]()
        var tmpContainer = container
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let typeContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Discriminator.self)
            let family: U? = try typeContainer.decodeIfPresent(U.self, forKey: U.discriminator)
            if let type = family?.getType() as? T.Type {
                list.append(try tmpContainer.decode(type))
            }
        }
        return list
    } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound {
        return nil
    } catch DecodingError.valueNotFound {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And this is where I've got to for a dictionary:

```
func decodeDictIfPresent<T : Decodable, U : ClassFamily>(family: U.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> [T: Any]? {
    do {
        var container = try self.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key)
        var dict = [T: Any]()
        var tmpContainer = container
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let typeContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Discriminator.self)
            let family: U? = try typeContainer.decodeIfPresent(U.self, forKey: U.discriminator)
            if let type = family?.getType() as? T.Type {
                list.append(try tmpContainer.decode(type))
            }
        }
        return dict
    } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound {
        return nil
    } catch DecodingError.valueNotFound {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Requirements:

```
protocol ClassFamily: Decodable {
    /// The discriminator key.
    static var discriminator: Discriminator { get }

    /// Returns the class type of the object coresponding to the value.
    func getType() -> AnyObject.Type
}

/// Discriminator key enum used to retrieve discriminator fields in JSON payloads.
enum Discriminator: String, CodingKey {
    case type = "type"
}
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the point of generics if then you throw it all out of the window by returning `[T:Any]?` in your `decodeDictIfPresent` function? Also, please [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve]. Those functions do not compile in their current states due to missing types `ClassFamily` and `Discriminator`.

Comment: Also, what type do you expect your function to return? In your question you mention `[(Heterogenous object) : CGFloat]` (which isn't a real type anyways), but then your func returns `[T:Any]?`, so which one is correct?

Comment: Sorry @DávidPásztor I'm doing my best!  I've added in the required Class Family & Discriminator. Ideally I can feed in the type by calling `decodeDictIfPresent([ClassFamily: CGFloat].self, forKey .someKey)` and the function would return [ClassC: 1.203, ClassB: 3.249, ClassC: 20.402] where ClassB & ClassC are implementations of ClassA. If I did the same but just with [ClassB, ClassC, ClassB] this would currently work fine. I've only just started playing with Generics so clearly have a lot to learn!